# What is the fluent object model to make this work?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, ienumerable

As practice for writing fluent APIs, I thought I'd make the following compile and run:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
        .When(i => i % 3 == 0).Then(i => Console.WriteLine("fizz"))
        .When(i => i % 5 == 0).Then(i => Console.WriteLine("buzz"))
        .Otherwise(i => Console.WriteLine(i))
        .Run();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The idea is `.When` will test each element in the enumeration, and if it passes the predicate, to have the action run.  If the predicate fails, the item is passed down the chain.

The graph I came up with was:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IConditionalEnumerable<T> When<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> test, Action<T> action)
    {
    }

    public static IResolvedEnumerable<T> Then<T>(this IConditionalEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> test, Action<T> action)
    {
    }

    public static void Run<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items) ;
    }
}

public interface IConditionalEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IResolvedEnumerable<T> Then<T>(IConditionalEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action);
}

public interface IResolvedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Otherwise(Action<T> behavior);
}
```

I am running into an issue -- `When` can't `foreach / yield return` inside of it, because the return type isn't directly `IEnumerable<T>` (although it inherits from it).  That has thrown a mental wrench into the gears.  What would the implementation of the extension methods look like?

Comment: Hint: Can you build the same fluent API that does **not** operate on sequences, but rather on individual values?  That is, can you write an extension not to `IEnumerable<T>`, but simply to, say `int` such that you can fizz-buzz an individual integer?  If so, then it is a straightforward process to extend it to sequences (or awaitables, or nullables, or whatever).

Comment: When you do so you'll discover that the problem has nothing at all to do with the fact that it is a *sequence*. The problem is that `Otherwise` somehow needs to know whether zero or non-zero number of `Then` clauses have already executed.

Comment: The next exercise you can try is: now try writing a fluent API equivalent to a "switch" where the body of the switch produces values. Suppose for instance we had `Switch(value).Case(v => someBool).Then(v => someVal).Case(v => someBool).Then(v => someVal).Otherwise(v => someVal)` where `value` and `someVal` can be of different types. Can you implement that? Can you then lift that to work on a sequence of values, and produce a sequence of results?

Comment: This `When(..).Then(...)` - shouldnt it be possible to return a `IEnumerable<(bool,T)>` from `When<T>` and apply `Then` only if the bool is true? (never tried to create fluents myself)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't worry about sequences. Just do it on values.

You can do this entirely with extension methods. Here's the thing:

- Somehow `Otherwise` needs to know whether any previous `Then` executed.
- Therefore somehow every `When` needs to know whether every previous `Then` executed.
- Every `Then` needs to know whether the previous `When` was true or false.

Here's the skeleton:

```
static class X 
{
    public enum WhenState { DoIt, DoNot }
    public enum ThenState { DidIt, DidNot }
    public static (T, ThenState) Begin<T>(this T item) { ... }
    public static (T, WhenState, ThenState) When<T>(
      this (T item, ThenState then) tuple, 
      Func<T, bool> p) { ... }
    public static (T, ThenState) Then<T>(
      this (T item, WhenState when, ThenState then) tuple, 
      Action<T> a) { ... }
    public static void Otherwise<T>(
      this (T item, ThenState then) tuple, 
      Action<T> a) { ... }
```

Once you implement those extension methods then you can do:

```
3.Begin().When(x => x % 3 == 0).Then( ... )
```

and so on.

Once you've got that implemented then it is easy to lift the operation to sequences. We have a device which turns values into actions; what is a device which turns a sequence of values into a sequence of actions?  It is built in to the language: `foreach(var item in items) item.Begin()...`.

Similarly, it is easy to lift the operation to any other monad. Say, nullable. We have a device which turns values into actions. What is a device to turn a nullable value into an action, or no action?  It is built into the language:  `x?.Begin()...`

Say you wish to apply your operation to a `Task<int>`; what is a device which turns a future value into a future action? `async Task DoIt(Task<T> task) { (await task).Begin()...`.

And so on. **Implement your operation on values, not on lifted values**; use the built-in lifting operations of the language to apply your operation to the lifted value to produce a lifted action.

Comment: I like the idea to avoid implementing these kinds of things for `IEnumerable<T>` since all that will tend to do is add a `foreach` loop. Gonna have to look at my `IEnumerable` extensions and see if there's anything like that I should simplify.

Comment: @Sahuagin: You might wonder why, if I believe we should do operations on values and not lifted values, that we have Select, Where, and SelectMany operate on sequences and not values. The signature of SelectMany should make it clear why it cannot operate on values; the premise of the operation is that it is *extracting values from a sequence to turn them into other sequences*. And Select and Where are just special versions of SelectMany that get their own methods for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt. I renamed the interfaces just for my understanding as I hacked it together.

```
public interface IWhen<T> {
    IThen<T> Then(Action<T> action);
}

public interface IThen<T> : IRun {
    IWhen<T> When(Func<T, bool> test);
    IRun Otherwise(Action<T> action);
}

public interface IRun {
    void Run();
}

public interface IRule<T> {
    Func<T, bool> Predicate { get; }
    Action<T> Invoke { get; }
}
```

And created the following implementations.

```
public class Rule<T> : IRule<T> {
    public Rule(Func<T, bool> predicate, Action<T> action) {
        this.Predicate = predicate;
        this.Invoke = action;
    }
    public Func<T, bool> Predicate { get; private set; }
    public Action<T> Invoke { get; private set; }
}

public class Then<T> : IThen<T> {
    private Queue<IRule<T>> rules = new Queue<IRule<T>>();
    private IEnumerable<T> source;

    public Then(IEnumerable<T> source, Queue<IRule<T>> rules) {
        this.source = source;
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    public IWhen<T> When(Func<T, bool> test) {
        var temp = new When<T>(source, test, rules);
        return temp;
    }

    public void Run() {
        foreach (var item in source) {
            var rule = rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Predicate(item));
            if (rule == null) continue;
            rule.Invoke(item);
        }
    }

    public IRun Otherwise(Action<T> action) {
        var rule = new Rule<T>(s => true, action);
        rules.Enqueue(rule);
        return new Then<T>(source, rules);
    }
}

public class When<T> : IWhen<T> {
    private Queue<IRule<T>> rules;
    private Func<T, bool> test;
    private IEnumerable<T> source;

    public When(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> test, Queue<IRule<T>> rules = null) {
        this.source = source;
        this.test = test;
        this.rules = rules ?? new Queue<IRule<T>>();
    }

    public IThen<T> Then(Action<T> action) {
        var rule = new Rule<T>(test, action);
        rules.Enqueue(rule);
        var then = new Then<T>(source, rules);
        return then;
    }
}
```

The extension method then looked like this to get started.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static IWhen<T> When<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> test) {
        var temp = new When<T>(source, test);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

And with that the following example in [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YbjsLR)

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
         Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
              .When(i => i % 3 == 0).Then(i => Console.WriteLine("fizz"))
              .When(i => i % 5 == 0).Then(i => Console.WriteLine("buzz"))
              .Otherwise(i => Console.WriteLine(i))
              .Run();
    }
}
```

produced

```
1
2
fizz
4
buzz
fizz
7
8
fizz
buzz
```

Comment: The goal is to produce the sequence `1, 2, fizz, 4, buzz, fizz, 7, 8, 9, buzz, 11, fizz, 13, 14, fizzbuzz...`

Comment: It's a reference to this article by one of the founders of this site. https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/

Comment: See my comments on the original question; this problem is easier to solve if you *don't* do it in sequences. We already have a mechanism for lifting actions on values into a sequence of actions on a sequence of values; it's called "foreach".

Comment: I really like this.  It does exactly what I wanted :)